# Does AWS CloudFront bill for the cache hit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I know that AWS CloudFront bills Data Transfer Out (and there's 1 TB of free in the free tier). But I was wondering what CloudFront counts as Data Transfer. Is any data transferred to the Internet (CloudFront cached data aka cache hit, data that is transferred from EC2/S3) billed?

**For instance**, let's say the origin server (EC2) returned 1 Gb of data to the Internet and CloudFront cached it, and eventually cached data got requested & transferred 4 times to the Internet. Will AWS bill me for 5 Gb of Data Transfer Out or only for 1 Gb (and the other 4 Gb won't be billed since it's cached)

**Just for context:** I have an EC2 application that returns images (that are stored in S3) and now I'm getting more and more requests and therefore more and more costs for the Data Transfer Out of EC2. I was looking for the option to cache images for some time in order to reduce Data Transfer costs. Two options that I found are **Cloudflare** & **CloudFront**. Cloudflare seems like a good option and allows to implement caching but in the meantime, I am trying to figure out how CloudFront works (since I'm using AWS ecosystem).

If that CloudFront bills every data transfer (even that is cached) then I suppose it won't reduce the Data Transfer cost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the docs say.

On **Origin server to Amazon CloudFront (origin fetches)**

> If you are using an AWS service as the origin for your content, data transferred from origin to edge locations (Amazon CloudFront origin fetches) **are free of charge**. This applies to data transfer from all AWS regions to all global CloudFront edge locations. Data transfer out from AWS services for **all non-origin fetch traffic** (such as multi-CDN traffic) to CloudFront **will incur their respective regional data transfer out charges**.

**Free data Transfer between AWS cloud services and Amazon CloudFront for origin fetches**

> If AWS origins such as Amazon S3, Amazon EC2 or Elastic Load Balancing are used, there is no charge incurred for data transferred from origins to CloudFront Edge locations (this type of data transfer is known as origin fetch).

[Here's detailed information on CloudFront Pricing along with a Price Calculator](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/).